# Passing Form to Controller MVC Using AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Want to ask how to pass form to controller MVC using AJAX. 
I have try various method like JSON.stringify, nothing works for me. My input name is an array. For example, Received[0].basketball, Received[1].basketball, Received[2].basketball. So the List should have Count = 3, but the list keep getting blank.

UPDATE: Include form id

```
public ActionResult Validate(List<Stuff> item)
{
   //null
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
    <input name="Receive[0].basketball" id="basketball' + x + '" value=""/>
    <input name="Receive[0].ball" id="ball' + x + '" value=""/>
    <input name="Receive[1].basketball" id="basketball' + x + '" value=""/>
    <input name="Receive[1].ball" id="ball' + x + '" value=""/>
}

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../Validate",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            item:  $('#form').serializeArray(),
        },
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to show your `Stuff` model. Your `name` attributes have no relationship to a `List<Stuff> item` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could use `serialize()` here

```
var datastring = $("#form").serialize();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../Validate",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: datastring,
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What does it do? (Is `#form` the correct ID for your form? Your question didn't include it)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var form = $('#form');
 var formData = $(form).serialize();

 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            success: function (result) 
        {

    }
});
```